# SMTP on razor webpages

Tags: razor

I'm writing razor syntax for web pages. My issue is that I have a table that contains employee email-address, and I want to send them an email after clicking any of their names from the form field.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
// Initialize WebMail helper
        WebMail.SmtpServer = "smtp.office365.com";
        WebMail.SmtpPort = 25;
        WebMail.UserName = "";
        WebMail.Password = "";
        WebMail.From = "";
        WebMail.EnableSsl = true;




//i want to send a message to an email
WebMail.Send(to: Email,
subject: "Visitor Alert",
body: " From: <br/> " + "Name: " + full_name + "<br/> " + " Mobile Number: " 
+ phone_number + "<br/> " + " Address :" + address);

//this is html part
<div class="form-group">
@{


var data = "SELECT FullName,Email From Employee ORDER BY Email";
var DB = Database.Open("VisitorConnectionString").Query(data);


<label>Whom to See</label>
<select class="form-control">

<option>---Select Staff---</option>
//here was to populate the name of the employees from database                                                                       
@foreach (var item in DB)
{


<option name="Email" value="@item.FullName">@item.FUllName</option>



 }


</select>
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

i've figured it out, wrote an sql statement to fetch the emails from the database,
then looped it together with the dropdown list.
thanks.